# Finding normalizing constant of joint density function

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Joint density function is as follows:
$$ f(x,y) = cx e^{-x(x+y)},\quad \text{ for } x>0, y>0$$ and is equal $0$ elsewhere.

My question is how do I find the normalizing constant c? I have tried working it out by expanding the exponential term and completing the square in hopes of simplifying it by using integrals involving normal pdfs but to no avail... Any solutions?

After Paul's suggestion,
$$c\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \;\mathrm{dx}$$ 
How do I deal with $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using limits from 0 to infinity for both dx and dy. This should be correct right?

Comment: the integral over all x and y of f(x,y) must be 1.

Comment: yes i did that. the problem i'm having here is how to separate the x and y so i can integrate them..

Comment: Integrate over y first

Comment: hold on let me try

Comment: oh I got it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral over the pdf must be 1, i.e
$$ c \cdot \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty x e^{-x(x+y)} dx dy = 1.$$

Integration over $y$ yields $\frac{1}{x}$ so that it remains to solve the integral 
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx.$$
Using the substitution $z=\sqrt{2} \cdot x$, we have to find
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}} dz.$$ The latter integral is - aside from a contant factor - the positive part of the standard normal.
All in all we get
$$c \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} = 1 $$ which immediately gives us c.

Comment: that substitution! i see.. that helps me! thanks!